# Save data into sql server using custom method in lightswitch html client

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-lightswitch

How to save data on button click(not by using save icon given by popup screen). I tried to use custom method like below. but data is not saving in sql database.

```
  myapp.AddEditApplicantDeclaration.SubmitMethod_execute = funcation(scree)
   {
       msls.application.commitChanges().then(null, function fail(e) {
       alert(e.message);
       msls.application.cancelChanges();
       throw e;
   });
   };
```

I created a button and write the _execute method. but its not saving into data base. Am i missing something here.
Its a simple table and trying to update isSummitted column into "Applicant" table.

Answer (score 0):

I save the data by simply using  `myapp.commitChanges();` ... this can be included within validation under the _execute of a button as you have above